# Is there a library to plot audio waveforms in flutter applications

Tags: flutter, dart, plot, signals

I want to plot some ECG data or any audio data waveform using flutter. What would be the best approach to do the same. I have explored many libraries such as mp_flutter but I haven't been able to figure out a way to import the data.

Answer (score 1):

### See [this,](https://matt.aimonetti.net/posts/2019-07-drawing-waveforms-in-flutter/) I found it helpful for my case

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware about any such library though but using a [CustomPainter](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/rendering/CustomPainter-class.html) should be a good start. Custom Paints are pretty easy to use

I hope [this example](https://github.com/apgapg/flutter_physics_concepts) helps you build your waveforms one of the example is shown below.

[image]